# NativeScript App Alert is still showing "About to Register at the end of lesson 3 in tutorial

Tags: nativescript

After completing the 3rd lesson "Application Logic" of the NativeScript Groceries tutorial, I am not getting the correct "Alert" message described as coded in login.component.ts. Instead I am still getting the "About to register......." Alert that was discussed earlier in the lessson. I should see a different message as shown in the signup function snippet.

```js
 signUp() {
      this.userService.register(this.user)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          alert("Your account was successfully created.");
          this.toggleDisplay();
        },
        () => alert("Unfortunately we were unable to create your account.")
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by updating NativeScript and required resources associated with it !